# Code got overwritten with the old code which was committed into github two days back. What should i do to get the local code?

Tags: git, github

**What should i do in order to get the old code back?**

I was working on my repository as usual.As i am new to GitHub i pushed my code 3 days ago.

Today in order to push the code i pulled it and my entire repository got replaced with old code.

All i did was using the below commands

```
git add .

git commit -m "your_name"

git remote add github *repo_link*

git remote -v

git push -f github repo_name
```

Please provide a solution so that i can i get my old code back.

Comment: I cannot see how you replaced your old code with the commands above. I think this migth help you https://guides.github.com/introduction/git-handbook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explained above, you forced push (`git push -f`) an old branch to the remote, effectively overriding whatever was there, so there are not many options left other than:

1-) Check if you still have the commits on your repository, on a different branch. In your code above you added a remote called `github`. If you originally cloned the repository from GitHub before, you might have your old branch in the `origin` remote (e.g. `origin/master`). In that case do a `git checkout origin/master` to see if your old code is still there

2-) Check if anyone else has a clone/fork of your repository with the old code and get a copy of that

3-) Try to recover the lost commit(s) using [git reflog](https://github.blog/2015-06-08-how-to-undo-almost-anything-with-git/#redo-after-undo-local)

4-) Try [contacting GitHub](https://support.github.com/contact) and see if they can restore your repo to a previous state